# Probability Question: Order of Sampling versus when order does not matter?

Tags: probability, statistics

50 Percent of voters support the president. What is the probability that, in a sample taken, 3 support the president and 2 do not? How does this differ from the probability found if the first three support the president and the last two do not?

Comment: I assume that the "sample taken" has five people in it? And what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let S represent supports and A represent is against.  In the first case, you count the case where you get SASAS and a number of other orders.  How many are there?  In the second case you only count SSSAA, so it will be a factor less likely.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the following method will appear in your course soon, if it hasn't already.
Let $X$ be the number of Supporters out of five randomly chosen voters.
Then $X$ has a binomial random variable with $n = 5$ and $p = P(\text{Support}) = 1/2.$ This is sometimes written $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(5, 1/2).$

Then the answer to the first question is 
$$P(X = 3) = {5 \choose 3}p^3(1-p)^2 = 10\left(\frac 1 2\right)^5 = 5/16.$$
The role of the factor ${5 \choose 3} = 10$ is to account for the ten
arrangements `SSSAA`, `SSASA`, ..., `AASSS`.

To answer the second question, you need to account for only *one* of the
ten arrangements.